# openID login in cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, openid, components

I am using cakePHP framework to build a website in which I want to let users signin using openID. and there is no core component in cake to do this.

- is there any component for openID login that is it differente from cakePHP Auth component ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes [there is](http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2008/02/06/new-version-of-the-openid-component/).

Comment: I just released a new version of this component this morning: http://code.42dh.com/openid/

Comment: @dhofstet The Openid example (http://openid-example.42dh.com/) doesn't works with an Google Acount like "myacount@gmail.com". It launchs an InvalidArgumentException on UsersController line 43. I tried right now.

Comment: Hello @Lobo, the correct string for google is https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id